# Godaddy Mail server and AWS DNS pointing

Tags: email, dns, aws-cli

I have purchased a domain in aws route 53 and created a business mail from godaddy. After creating mail in godaddy, it is prividing me some recordsets such as MX record, cname record etc. I have added these records in AWS route 53 hosted zone. But still not getting to activate my mail. Anyone Please help me to fix it out.

Comment: what exactly have is the error you are getting ?

Comment: When I check in the MX toolbox, it is showing DNS record not found

Comment: You currently have no MX records.  Check your Route53 settings again as they didn't save correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the NS records for your domain as your authoritative DNS server at the domain registrar (where you purchased your domain from)

Comment: GoDaddy business email is providing me to set cname, MX and srv records. All these records I have set in AWS route 53 hosted zone. Still the configuration is not complete

Comment: You need to add the NS record first, on the where you purchased the domain. If you can share your domain name  may be I can help further.

Comment: Yes I have added the ns record. My domain name is www.liwasun.com